# Configuration error running Zope: No database configured

Tags: plone, zope

I received the following error when I try to start Zope with the command
after trying to install the add-on CalendarX. I have just modified the `buildout.cnf` at `/zinstance` directory and ran the `buildout` located at `/bin`. After that I ran in debug mode and caught the following errors. What can I do to revert changes or restart server correctly configured?

Errors:

```
:/var/plone/zinstance# ./bin/plonectl fg
instance: /var/plone/zinstance/parts/instance/bin/runzope -X debug-mode=on
2013-04-02 10:31:40 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Tue Apr  2 10:31:40 2013
        Hostname: 0.0.0.0
        Port: 8080
2013-04-02 10:31:40 INFO Zope Set effective user to "plone"
2013-04-02 10:31:41 INFO Marshall libxml2-python not available. Unable to register libxml2 based marshallers.
/var/plone/Zope-2.10.7-final-py2.4/lib/python/Products/COREBlog2/configuration/schema.xml
2013-04-02 10:31:44 INFO Plone Dependency
Unable to detect Zope version. Please make sure you have Zope 2.10.4 or newer installed.
2013-04-02 10:31:44 WARNING SecurityInfo Conflicting security declarations for "getTags"
2013-04-02 10:31:44 WARNING SecurityInfo Class "COREBlogEntry" had conflicting security declarations
2013-04-02 10:31:46 INFO Plone Python does not have SSL support. OpenID support not available
2013-04-02 10:31:49 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.LDAPMultiPlugins' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it.

2013-04-02 10:31:49 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.LDAPUserFolder' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it.

2013-04-02 10:31:49 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.PloneLDAP' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it.

2013-04-02 10:31:49 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.sevillaSkin2' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it.

2013-04-02 10:31:49 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.sevillaSkin3' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it.

2013-04-02 10:31:49 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.sevillaSkin_' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it.

2013-04-02 10:31:49 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.sevillaSkin_1' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it.

2013-04-02 10:31:49 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.sevillaSkin_2' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it.

2013-04-02 10:31:49 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.sevillaSkin_23_06' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it.

2013-04-02 10:31:49 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.sevillaSkin_new' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it.

2013-04-02 10:31:49 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.sevillaSkin_old' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it.

2013-04-02 10:31:50 INFO PloneFormGen Patching plone.app.portlets ColumnPortletManagerRenderer to not catch Retry exceptions
2013-04-02 10:31:50 INFO Zope Ready to handle requests
2013-04-02 10:31:55 ERROR Zope.ZODBMountPoint Failed to mount database. ZConfig.ConfigurationError (No database configured for mount point at /site1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Zope-2.10.7-final-py2.4/lib/python/Products/ZODBMountPoint/MountedObject.py", line 257, in _getOrOpenObject
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Zope-2.10.7-final-py2.4/lib/python/Products/ZODBMountPoint/MountedObject.py", line 147, in _getMountedConnection
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Zope-2.10.7-final-py2.4/lib/python/Products/ZODBMountPoint/MountedObject.py", line 157, in _getDB
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Zope-2.10.7-final-py2.4/lib/python/Zope2/Startup/datatypes.py", line 276, in getDatabase
    name = self.getName(mount_path)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Zope-2.10.7-final-py2.4/lib/python/Zope2/Startup/datatypes.py", line 293, in getName
    self._mountPathError(mount_path)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Zope-2.10.7-final-py2.4/lib/python/Zope2/Startup/datatypes.py", line 268, in _mountPathError
    raise ConfigurationError(
ConfigurationError: No database configured for mount point at /site1
2013-04-02 10:31:55 ERROR Zope.ZODBMountPoint Failed to mount database. ZConfig.ConfigurationError (No database configured for mount point at /site1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Zope-2.10.7-final-py2.4/lib/python/Products/ZODBMountPoint/MountedObject.py", line 257, in _getOrOpenObject
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Zope-2.10.7-final-py2.4/lib/python/Products/ZODBMountPoint/MountedObject.py", line 147, in _getMountedConnection
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Zope-2.10.7-final-py2.4/lib/python/Products/ZODBMountPoint/MountedObject.py", line 157, in _getDB
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Zope-2.10.7-final-py2.4/lib/python/Zope2/Startup/datatypes.py", line 276, in getDatabase
    name = self.getName(mount_path)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Zope-2.10.7-final-py2.4/lib/python/Zope2/Startup/datatypes.py", line 293, in getName
    self._mountPathError(mount_path)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Zope-2.10.7-final-py2.4/lib/python/Zope2/Startup/datatypes.py", line 268, in _mountPathError
    raise ConfigurationError(
ConfigurationError: No database configured for mount point at /site1
^C2013-04-02 10:38:47 INFO SignalHandler Caught signal SIGINT
2013-04-02 10:38:47 INFO Z2 Shutting down
```

Any help? 
Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally got the solution.

1) Stop Zope instance (plonectl or whatever):

```
$./bin/plonectl stop
```

2) Fill your zope.conf file correctly.
Should look something like this.

```
<zodb_db main>
    # Main database
    cache-size 5000

# FileStorage database
    <filestorage>
      path /var/plone/zinstance/var/filestorage/Data.fs
    </filestorage>
    mount-point /
</zodb_db>
<zodb_db site1>
    <filestorage>
      path /var/plone/zinstance/var/filestorage3/Data.fs
    </filestorage>
    mount-point /site1
</zodb_db>
```

3) Rerun buildout:

```
$./bin/buildout
```

4) Start zope instance:

```
$./bin/plonectl start (normal mode)
$./bin/plonectl fg (debug mode)
```

When you run `buildout` the `zope.conf` file changes.